# Will Samsung Galaxy Nexus i9250 work with Indian SIM Cards?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, sim-unlocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)

I understand that Samsung has stated they will not launch Samsung Galaxy Nexus i9250 in India and hence am planning to buy it from Amazon. Was just wondering if the unlocked version of the phone would work well with Indian SIM Card? Please advise.

Comment: Ya it will work..
I am using it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mine from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details/Galaxy_Nexus_HSPA) from one of my friends coming from US. And it works just like that. There are no hardware / software shortcomings at least as of till now except for being not able to access Play Store, Play Music and other geo-location specific apps.

I got upgraded to Jellybean as well almost immediately.

Just in case, if its useful, I am with Airtel.

If you buy it from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005ZEF01A), its costlier at least by $60. I would suggest order it from Google Play. And ask one of your friends to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks @prashanth. I need it shipped to India hence was relying on Amazon. Worried if the legal battle between Apple and Samsung may result in rejection of my order at Amazon.

Answer (score 3):

The phone [specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_nexus-4219.php) says it supports the following frequencies:

> 2G Network    GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900
>
> 3G Network    HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100

I think this is almost all the frequency, so the phone should work in India.

Comment: Thanks @roxan.  Would there be any other hardware/software shortcomings ? I would most probably be using Vodafone SIM Card.

Comment: There wouldn't except things like Google Wallet which doesn't have any function in India. If you find the answer helpful you should upvote/accept it.