# How do I switch my htc merge from us cellular to t-mobile?

Tags: carriers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)

I have unlocked it and I am trying to s-off, I am ignorant to cell hacking/programing ad don't know if I am doing anything that will help or hinder my operation. I have just been following youtube or sites advice but so far nothing has really helped. I have the t-mobile sim card but us cellulars programing is preventing service.

Please help(and use laymans terms cause like I said I am not too savy when it comes to this).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. [HTC Merge](http://m.gsmarena.com/htc_merge-3739.php) is a CDMA phone and [US Cellular](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Cellular#section_3.) is a CDMA network, while [T-Mobile](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Mobile) is a GSM carrier. The two technologies are not compatible, and it's not possible to use phones between them.