# Google Nexus 4 on Verizon?

Tags: verizon, nexus-4

I currently own a Motorola Droid 3 on Verizon.

I wish to purchase a LG Nexus 4 directly from Google - will it work on my Verizon Network? Or would it be a waste of time?

Comment: As per our FAQ, shopping suggestions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: See also [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29677)

Answer (score 5):

It would be a wast of time (and money). The phone is not compatible with Verizon's network.

Verizon is a CDMA network, and the Nexus 4 from Google is GSM phone.

In the past Google has met-in-the-middle with Verizon and released the CDMA compatible Galaxy Nexus - this time there appear to be no plans on releasing a CDMA compatible Nexus 4 (possibly due to the slow turnaround time Verizon had on releasing updates to the Galaxy Nexus).