# LG Nexus 4 compatibility Airtel India

Tags: carriers, compatibility, nexus-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)

I plan to purchase the LG Nexus 4 from the US on the release date (13th November). The phone claims to be unlocked. But will it be compatible with Airtel in India for both data and call services?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be compatible. Google has already mentioned that it will be compatible with over 200 networks worldwide. That includes Airtel India as well.

I have bunch of friends who are using Galaxy Nexus in India. Voice calls and 3G/2G works smoothly. The same should be true about Nexus 4 as it is also an unlocked device like the Galaxy Nexus.