# Nexus 4 And Vodafone india

Tags: nexus-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)

I am buying the Nexus 4 from US google play store and my colleague is sending it over via his relative. My question is even though google has mentioned that the unlocked version being sold on play store is supported by 200 carriers worldwide - will there be any issues with Vodafone India or is there any carrier that i need to purchase Sim from. Please reply immediately as i am kind of worried here.

Thanks in advance
Sameer

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem per se. You will need to use a smaller size SIM card than the standard, so consult your local Vodafone shop to see if they have it in that size.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than answering your question directly, I will point some things to you on which you should read and research yourself, and find out the answer.

OK, First of all, head over to gsmarena.com and check out the 2G and 3G network specs for your phone.It will have several frequencies listed. Now check which frequenc(y/ies) Vodafone India uses for its 2G and 3G network.(You might have to do quite a bit of googling for this) If any one (or maybe more) frequencies are same in both cases then your phone will definitely work over Vodafone India's network.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I found below two links and that answers my questions.
http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_4_e960-5048.php

http://cellsignalboosters.in/vodafone.html

THanks guys!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)