# Can I flash my carrier-locked phone to a firmware for a different region and/or carrier?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung, device-firmware

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 (I9050) which is locked to the EE network in the United Kingdom.

Its firmware PDA ends with "MDD" and the carrier code is "EVR".

There is a newer firmware available for region: Germany at [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2252982) whose PDA is I9505XXUAMDM.

Can I flash my device with this firmware and use it in the UK? Do I need to be rooted and/or unlocked to do this?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)