# Configure Australian Phone to work on US Network

Tags: mobile-network

I have an HTC Desire HD (unlocked) purchased in Australia, currently operating on a T-Mobile network but I am not getting any data service. I purchased an activation kit from Amazon and the $30/mth unlimited data package from Walmart. Text and voice are working fine, but I am not receiving any data.

The data plan is a 4g plan but I assumed that would also include 3G for those without 4G phones.

On the phone settings, T-Mobile is listed under settings > Wireless & networks > mobile networks > Network Operators. When I select Network Operators > Select Automatically it flashes up a message "registered on network".

Is there something I must do to get my phone to work here? OS = Gingerbread.

Comment: Check for your APN settings - found in Settings > Wireless & Network settings > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names.

Comment: Thanks. I found some APN settings on the T-Mobile site, and it is working, but very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The "international" version of the HTC Desire HD is not hardware compatible with T-Mobile USA's 3G frequency bands. The phone's antennas support HSPA on the 900 and 2100 MHz frequencies (the North American GSM variants should work, though: [source](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_hd-3468.php)), and software settings will not have any effect on this. [T-Mobile's 3G network uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Mobile_US#Radio_frequency_spectrum_chart):

- 850 MHz: Acquired via a roaming agreement as part of the failed AT&T merger
- 1700/2100 MHz AWS: the device must support *both* of these frequencies to work because the 1700 band is used for uplink and the 2100 band is used for downlink.
- 1900 MHz

As you can see, these do not line up (excepting **half** of the AWS band, which is not sufficient). You'll need a new phone if you want 3G service. See [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier) for suggestions on how to determine which phones will work.

Comment: Thanks. I think you must be approximately correct. I am receiving very slow internet after changing my APN settings as indicated above. Cheers.