# XYZ X1 Change band from 900 to 850

Tags: gsm

I just bought the XYZ X1 Android phone with GSM: 900/1800MHz, WCDMA 2100 MHz
Unfortunately in my country are 850/1900MHz frequences.

Is it possible to change the band on this phone?

I've tried to change the band from terminal:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ am start -n com.android.settings/.BandMode
```

Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.BandMode }

But only limited list was shown:

```
Automatic
EURO Band
JAPAN Band
AUS Band
AUS2 Band
```

But there is no my band here, any idea how can I get it? Maybe base-band upgrade? thank you.

Comment: This is a design of the hardware. The only way to change it would be to disassemble the phone and install your own antennas somehow (which is not at all trivial). [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29677) has a lot of information related to this.

Comment: I saw in internet that almost all tri-band phones could change their bands. How do you know that mine can't be changed? Thank you.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to where you saw that? Wherever you read that was wrong or perhaps using terminology loosely. If you could change a phone's supported bands anytime you wanted, then there'd be no need to even bother listing them on a spec sheet or manufacturing different phone varieties.

Comment: there are many places. http://www.movilesdualsim.com/foro/threads/20835-activar-banda-WCDMA-900-en-terminales-chinos/page8 in spanish for example. As I understand, dual band means, working on two bands on the same time, but some phones could have options which bands would you prefer. this is the other post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36948876 Just need to figure out if my phones supports the band change

Comment: That's a completely different situation, though. The hardware of the phone in that XDA thread (the S5830-L) supports both sets of bands. Look at [the spec sheet](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_ace_s5830-3724.php). The idea there is to essentially force the phone to stick to using one if its supported bands instead of another one, not adding support for a entirely different (and unsupported) band. That's not the case for your device.

Comment: Maybe you are right, just wanted to check every possible solution before buy the new phone. Thank you.