# HTC Desire P voice/MMS works, but 3G doesn't

Tags: htc, 3g

I brought a phone (HTC Desire P) from overseas to U.S.A. I got a voice/data plan with AT&T. We tested the voice but forgot to test data, and later found that the 3G data isn't working.

I tried to turn on mobile from the both from the UI (it auto disconnects after several seconds) and with the android debugger:

```
adb.exe shell data enable
```

but I get "Permission denied".

Does anyone know anything that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The [HTC Desire P](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_p-6123.php) does not support AT&T's 3G frequency bands. Its antennas support the 900 and 2100 MHz frequencies, whereas AT&T has deployed 3G [on the 850 and 1900 MHz bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T_Mobility#Radio_frequency_summary).

You cannot use your phone on AT&T's 3G network. If you want to determine if another device would be compatible, you may wish to look at [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)